# Export path doesn't remember when I close terminal window

Tags: linux, ubuntu

When I export to path:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH" && eval "$(pyenv init --path)" && echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n eval "$(pyenv init -)"\nfi' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Terminal remembers pyenv.

But when I close window and open a new terminal window, terminal doesn't remember pyenv command.

What am I missing? How can I add pyenv to terminal as a permanent command?

Comment: Setting an environment variable (like `PATH`) only effects the current process (and its children). To make this command persistent you would need to place it in a shell initialization file (like `~/.bashrc`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to save it to a file, so the terminal can remember it the next time you open the window.

This question is previously answered for Unix and Linux systems [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/117470) by Kiwy.

In a nutshell, you can try this command to save the environment variable in a `.profile` file:

```bash
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

The assumption is that you use the `bash` shell on a Unix/Linux system. For other systems and shells, this command may not work. You can check out Kiwy's answer for reference on other shells.

I hope this helped you!

Comment: Didn't work. Forgets pyenv in new window.

Comment: I have updated my answer to use the `~/.bashrc` file instead. The shell reads different files according to login and interactivity type (see more [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170499)). Also, close the terminal application fully before checking if the variable has been set - just opening a new window may not work.